# Laravel 4.1 - Input::old() escaping input issue

Tags: laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.1 to create a new project.
I have a issue when submiting a form with quotes which are escaped every time i submit the form. 
The problem still even i use `{{ }} or {{{ }}}`
here is how it looks :

[image]

And when I submit the form I got this :

[image]

So how to display for example :  `Smith'` instead of `Smith\'` ?

**EDIT**

View :

```
             {{
                Form::open(array('action' => 'UserController@postAccount',
                'id' => '_update-account-form',
                'class' => 'form-horizontal update-account-form',
                'role' => 'form'))
                }}

           <input type="text" name="last_name" 
           value="{{{ Input::old('last_name') }}}"   
           class="form-control" id="last-name" >
```

UserController :

public function postAccount()
    {

```
    $validator = new \Services\Validators\User;

    if ($validator->passes('account')) {
        // Save data
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

        $user->last_name  = Input::get('last_name');
        $user->first_name = Input::get('first_name');
        $user->birthday   = Input::get('birthday');
        $user->newsletter = Input::get('newsletter');
        $user->save();

        return Redirect::action('UserController@getAccount')
            ->with('success', 'Changes saved');


    }
```

Comment: can you show some code ? how does your template and controller look?

Comment: I know this question is a bit old now but I've just fixed this problem myself by turning of the magic quotes  [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) on my shared hosting as somehow my host is using it by default...